# how to check the click event handler for ms chart control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mschart, mouseclick-event

Hi I am using ms chart control in win-forms application.

I have a problem with mouse click event handler for chart control. I need to check that  like this if the mouse click event for chart control is true then do something  like this i have done the code like this

```
        bool this.kpiChartControl.MouseClick = false;


        if (this.kpiChartControl.MouseClick != true)
        {
                //do something.....
        }


   ERROR :  The event system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick can only appear on left hand side of += or -=
```

would any one pls help on this.......

I need to check like this if mouse click event for mschart is true " do something "....

Modified code    :

```
 this.kpiChartControl.MouseClick+= new MouseEventHandler(void (object , MouseEventArgs e))
```

still it was giving error can any help me on this...

MODIFIED CODE :

```
       if( this.kpiChartControl.MouseClick+= new MouseEventHandler(void (object  sender , MouseEventArgs e)) == true)
      {
         // do something

       }
```

Error :Invalid term Void

Comment: If you mean to check if its got an assignment, eg something to do if the event fires, thats different. "MouseClick" or do you mean you want to tell if the mouse button is down?

Comment: @bugfinder  Ya  if i click on the ms chart i need to do something i.e mouse click event ... I dont know how to check but i have tried  above code

Comment: @bugfinder would you pls help me on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register to the event; as such:

> this.kpiChartControl.MouseClick += (obj, sender) => {  //Do something
>   }

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx

Comment: ya i  have tried like this but it was giving error    this.kpiChartControl.MouseClick+= new MouseEventHandler(void (object , MouseEventArgs e));

Comment: Have you read the events tutorial? And could you post the entire error.

Comment: Would you please look at the tutorial? You have to read the documentation in order to get anywhere, now you are just making syntax up.

Comment: I have read that tutorial but I dont know how to implement  that  one  into my program...

Comment: pls look at this question     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791311/trying-to-show-the-two-graphs-on-same-page