# trying to show the two graphs on same page

Tags: c#, .net, graph, charts, mschart

I am using win forms application
    I am using single ms chart control and generating two different charts and want to show two on same page by using  bool overview      (this means when the applications runs one graph will be shown and if you click on that graph i want to show another one along  with this one )  by the following code

```
      private void chartControlMemberTotals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

       kpiMemberTotalsForm.DrawKpi(this.chartControlMemberTotals, startDate, endDate, true);
     }





 public void DrawKpi(Chart targetChartControl, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, bool Overview)
{
  try
  {    
    Series series = null;
    Title title;
    string area;


     targetChartControl.ChartAreas.Clear();
      targetChartControl.Series.Clear();
      targetChartControl.Titles.Clear();

        area = "Status";
      targetChartControl.ChartAreas.Add(area);
      series = targetChartControl.Series.Add(area);
      series.ChartArea = area;
      if (!Overview)
      {
        title = targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Member status");
        title.IsDockedInsideChartArea = Overview;
        title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        title.DockedToChartArea = area;


        targetChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;
      }

      targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Members status").DockedToChartArea = area;

      area = " Live members mebershiptypes";
      targetChartControl.ChartAreas.Add(area);
      series = targetChartControl.Series.Add(area);
      series.ChartArea = area;

      if (!Overview)
      {
        title = targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Live Status  members  By MemberShip Type");
        title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        title.DockedToChartArea = area;

        targetChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;
        targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Live memberships").DockedToChartArea = area;
      }


      foreach (Title chartTitle in targetChartControl.Titles)
      {
        chartTitle.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
      }

      foreach (ChartArea chartArea in targetChartControl.ChartAreas)
      {
        chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
      }

      if (!Overview)
      {
        foreach (Series chartSerie in targetChartControl.Series)
        {


          chartSerie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
          chartSerie["ColumnDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
          chartSerie["LabelStyle"] = "Top";
          chartSerie.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    //series.CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=Cylinder";
        chartSerie.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;

        }
      }

      foreach (Series chartSeries in targetChartControl.Series)
      {
        chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

        if (!Overview)
        {
          chartSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        }
        else
        {

          chartSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
        }
        chartSeries["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
        chartSeries["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";

        chartSeries.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
      }

      foreach (Legend legend in targetChartControl.Legends)
      {
        legend.Enabled = false;
      }

      if (!Overview)
      {
        DataTable Accept = null;
        Accept = KPIData.livemembersmembershiptype(mf);
        targetChartControl.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(Accept.Rows, "mshipname", Accept.Rows, "count");

        foreach (Series chartSeries in targetChartControl.Series)
        {
          foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
          {

            switch (point.AxisLabel)
            {
              case "Silver membership": point.Color = Color.Red; break;

            }
            point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]);
          }
        }
      }
      DataTable reportsfull = null;
      reportsfull = KPIData.MembershipTotals(StartDate, EndDate, mf);

        targetChartControl.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(reportsfull.Rows, "Status", reportsfull.Rows, "Value");


        foreach (Series chartSeries in targetChartControl.Series)
        {
          foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
          {
            switch (point.AxisLabel)
            {
              case "New": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break;
              case "Live": point.Color = Color.Green; break;

            }

            point.Label = string.Format("{0:0} - {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel);
          }
        }
    }
 catch
  {
  }
  }
```

but when the application runs it shows the graph and when i clicking on the graph it shows only one graph i dont know why it was not showing another graph

is there any mistake for specifying the series and legends for the ms chart and the data is coming from database is correct

Comment: Is there any problem with legend and series ...would any one help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, You are databinding the same series `targetChartControl.Series[0]`.
I think you need to try defining two separate chart series and assign them to the two different chart areas that you already defined. That should solve your issue.